# How to Hiding application source when posting to Facebook page via graph API

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've successfully posted to a fan page as the actual page via the Graph API.

The problem is that the post says it was posted at "time via application name". Is there any way to hide this, so my post looks exactly as if I typed it directly into Facebook?
Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

*Short answer:* No.

*Slightly long answer:*

Unfortunately, if such a feature was to be available, it would have to be made available by Facebook via their SDK / API. As of now, however, anytime anything is published via any third-party application, they will continue to bear the *via application name* stamp on their posts.

Why I say that Facebook will have to implement such a feature is because Twitter did exactly that. Sometime in mid 2012 I think. This was possibly done to bringing parity across the entire platform. * Source: http://thenextweb.com/twitter/2012/08/28/twitter-longer-displays-client-tweet-posted-web-emphasizing-first-party-reading-experience/*

I suspect this is because you can only do a limited set of actions (when posting on Twitter) as compared to the Facebook platform. On Facebook, you have several choices when posting content to the platform. Images, Videos, Links, Status updates. And I am not even counting the Open Graph actions.

You could consider filing a [feature request to Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/contact/). If they think the suggestion merits inclusion, they just might do it.

Comment: @ManojKumar: No problem. I'm afraid there is no solution per-se at the moment.

Comment: Is there any possible workaround for this problem? For example, is there a way to set up a link to manually click to post?

Comment: @DelosChang: Unfortunately, none. That is how Facebook does it. :-(